# Recursive Generic Definition

Tags: c#, generics, clr, nested-generics

So I was watching this video of the awesome Jon Skeet: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3DkISWIouY4 (watch from the beginning to see the part I'm going to ask you about!)

So consider the following code:

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var x = new DeepContainer<string>();

    }
}

public class DeepContainer<T> : SimpleContainer<DeepContainer<DeepContainer<T>>>
{
    public DeepContainer()
    {

    }
}

public class SimpleContainer<TSomething>
{
    public TSomething Something { get; set; }

    public SimpleContainer()
    {
    }
}
```

We know that this won't run, as for reasons that we cannot expand TSomething to it's actual type, it will be `<SimpleContainer<SimpleContainer<SimpleContainer<SimpleContainer...`

However if we change the definition of `DeepContainer<T>` to this:

```
public class DeepContainer<T> : SimpleContainer<DeepContainer<T>> // One level of Deepcontainer omitted
```

All of the sudden it works.

However, in my mind it does not. Because when I try to expand the type of TSomething I get:
`SimpleContainer<SimpleContainer<SimpleContainer<SimpleContainer<SimpleContainer`.

I can't get my mind over how this works.

Comment: The problem is it *will* compile - but it goes bang at execution time. And it makes my head hurt too. (Note that I didn't come up with this example - the good folks at JetBrains did.)

Comment: Right. It'll compile, not run. I'll change it tomorrow (too hard from phone).

Comment: See also http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/05/07/covariance-and-contravariance-part-twelve-to-infinity-but-not-beyond.aspx if you're into this sort of thing.